# Menú de 3 opciones

Tags: c#

Este es mi menú hasta ahora

```
  int opcion;;
  Console.WriteLine("Menú");
  Console.WriteLine("1) Cargar alumnos");
  Console.WriteLine("2) Mostrar alumnos");
  Console.WriteLine("3) Salir");
  Console.WriteLine("Eliga una opcion");
```

Después cree los objetos para ingresar los alumnos, (pongo uno así no es tan denso)

```
Alumnos aaa = new Alumnos();
if (opcion == 1)
           {
Console.WriteLine("Ingresar nombre: ");
aaa.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Ingresar apellido: ");
aaa.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Ingresar documento: ");
aaa.DNI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Ingresar domicilio: ");
aaa.Domicilio = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Quiero saber como podre mostrar esos datos en la opción 2 y como volver a mostrar el menú después de completar la opción 1. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Por favor cuando formatees bloques de código no uses la backtick, en su lugar selecciona dicho bloque y presiona `ctrl + k` o presiona el icono de `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Podria ser algo como esto

```
static void Main()
{
    int opcion = 0;

    while(opcion <> 3)
    {
        Alumnos aaa = null;

        Console.WriteLine("Menú");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Cargar alumnos");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Mostrar alumnos");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Salir");
        Console.WriteLine("Eliga una opcion");
        int opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());


        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                alumno = Cargar();
                break;

            case 2:
                Mostrar(alumno);
                break;
        } 

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }
}


static Alumnos Cargar()
{
    Alumnos aaa = new Alumnos();

    Console.WriteLine("Ingresar nombre: ");
    aaa.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Ingresar apellido: ");
    aaa.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Ingresar documento: ");
    aaa.DNI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Ingresar domicilio: ");
    aaa.Domicilio = Console.ReadLine();

    return aaa;
}

static void Mostrar(Alumnos aaa)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alumno: {0}, {1} DNI:{3} ", aaa.Nombre, aaa.Apellido, aaa.DNI);

}
```

La idea seria separar en funciones para que el codigo este mas prolijo, despeus generas un loop hasta que la opcion seleccionada sea de salida, mientras tanto repites el menu limpiando la consola